# Синоним highload -> нагруженные-системы

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Меткой [highload](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highload) помечен 31 вопрос, меткой [нагруженные-системы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b) помечено 13 вопросов.

Предлагаю оставить русскую метку [нагруженные-системы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b), а [highload](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highload) сделать синонимом.

Comment: нагруженные-системы - как-то длинно. highload - это более читаемо, всеми понимаемо. Я бы проголосовал за удаление "нагруженные-системы"

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, смысл в вашей аргументации есть, можете завести ответ в пользу вашего варианта? Чтобы получилось голосование?

Comment: Highload - это не просто нагруженные, это высоконагруженные. Для метки слишком уж длинно )

Comment: @PashaPash, согласно голосам надо бы синонимизацию отразить в другую сторону.

Comment: @alexolut ок, развернул

Comment: @PashaPash что-то не видно пока. Кэш?

Comment: @NickVolynkin с [функциональщиной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) не поспоришь.

Comment: @alexolut да, скорее всего. вообще я только метку поставил, а тэги уже давно слили :)

Comment: @PashaPash хех, теперь при клике на синоним [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/highload/info) получаю 404. Кажется, мы знаем кого винить :-D

Comment: Кажется, рассосалось.

Comment: @alexolut не понял про функциональщину.

Comment: @NickVolynkin метка, для которой предельную [длину увеличивали](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5546/176217).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**За удаление метки "нагруженные-системы"**

Нагруженные-системы - это длинно, состоит из двух слов. highload - это проще читаемо, всеми понимаемо.

Comment: Может, не удалить, а синонимизировать и объединить?

Comment: Подразумевалось синонимизирование, но хотелось бы, чтобы именно "нагруженные-системы" было синонимом , а метка highload осталась как основная.

Comment: Предложил "нагруженные-системы" в качестве синонима для "highload".